# How to "remember" categorical encodings for actual predictions after training?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Suppose wanted to train a machine learning algorithm on some dataset including some categorical parameters. (New to machine learning, but my thinking is...) Even if converted all the categorical data to 1-hot-encoded vectors, how will this encoding map be "remembered" after training?

Eg. converting the initial dataset to use 1-hot encoding before training, say

```
universe of categories for some column c is {"good","bad","ok"}, so convert rows to
[1, 2, "good"] ---> [1, 2, [1, 0, 0]],
[3, 4, "bad"]  ---> [3, 4, [0, 1, 0]],
...
```

, after training the model, all future prediction inputs would need to use the same encoding scheme for column c.

How then during future predictions will data inputs remember that mapping (where "good" maps to index 0, etc.) (Specifically, when planning on using a `keras` RNN or LSTM model)? Do I need to save it somewhere (eg. python pickle)(if so, how do I get the explicit mapping)? Or is there a way to have the model automatically handle categorical inputs internally so can just input the original label data during training and future use?

If anything in this question shows any serious confusion on my part about something, please let me know (again, very new to ML).

** Wasn't sure if this belongs in https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but posted here since specifically wanted to know how to deal with the actual code implementation of this problem.

Comment: Just remember this mapping and use it for future predictions

Comment: @rvinas Was planning on doing this. Jut wanted to make sure that was not missing out on some other best-practice method. Have provided my own answer of a draft of what I was planning to do. If there is something wrong with the basic strategy there, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought would be to do something like this on the training/testing dataset D (*using a mix of python and plain psudo-code*):

1. Do something like

```py
    # Before: D.schema == {num_col_1: int, cat_col_1: str, cat_col_2: str, ...}

    # assign unique index for each distinct label for categorical column annd store in a new column
    # http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer
    label_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="cat_col_i", outputCol="cat_col_i_index").fit(D)
    D = label_indexer.transform(D)

    # After: D.schema == {num_col_1: int, cat_col_1: str, cat_col_2: str, ..., cat_col_1_index: int, cat_col_2_index: int, ...}
```

for all the categorical columns

2. Then for all of these categorical name and index columns in D, make a map of form

```py
    map = {}
    for all categorical column names colname in D:
        map[colname] = []
        # create mapping dict for all categorical values for all 
        # see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations
        for all rows r in D.select(colname, '%s_index' % colname).drop_duplicates():
            enc_from = r['%s' % colname]
            enc_to = r['%s_index' % colname]
            map[colname].append((enc_from, enc_to))

        # for cats that may appear later that have yet to be seen 
        # (IDK if this is best practice, may be another way, see https://medium.com/@vaibhavshukla182/how-to-solve-mismatch-in-train-and-test-set-after-categorical-encoding-8320ed03552f)
        map[colname].append(('NOVEL_CAT', map[colname].len))
        # sort by index encoding
        map[colname].sort(key = lamdba pair: pair[1])
```

to end up with something like

```
    {
        'cat_col_1': [('orig_label_11', 0), ('orig_label_12', 1), ...],
        'cat_col_2': [(), (), ...],
        ...
        'cat_col_n': [(orig_label_n1, 0), ...]
    }
```

which can then be used to generate 1-hot-encoded vectors for each categorical column in any later data sample row ds. Eg.

```py
    for all categorical column names colname in ds:
        enc_from = ds[colname]
        # make zero vector for 1-hot for category 
        col_onehot = zeros.(size = map[colname].len)
        for label, index in map[colname]:
            if (label == enc_from):
                col_onehot[index] = 1
                # make new column in sample for 1-hot vector
                ds['%s_onehot' % colname] = col_onehot
                break
```

3. Can then save this structure as pickle `pickle.dump( map, open( "cats_map.pkl", "wb" ) )` to use to compare against categorical column values when making *actual* predictions later.

** There may be a better way, but I think would need to better understand this article (https://medium.com/@satnalikamayank12/on-learning-embeddings-for-categorical-data-using-keras-165ff2773fc9). Will update answer if anything.

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is the following:

After you use StringIndexer.fit(), you can save its metadata (includes the actual encoder mapping, like "good" being the first column)

This is the following code I use (using java, but can be adjusted to python):

```
StringIndexerModel sim = new StringIndexer()
        .setInputCol(field)
        .setOutputCol(field + "_INDEX")
        .setHandleInvalid("skip")
        .fit(dataset);

sim.write().overwrite().save("IndexMappingModels/" + field + "_INDEX");
```

and later, when trying to make predictions on a new dataset, you can load the stored metadata:

```
StringIndexerModel sim = StringIndexerModel.load("IndexMappingModels/" + field + "_INDEX");

dataset = sim.transform(dataset);
```

I imagine you have already solved this issue, since it was posted in 2018, but I've not found this solution anywhere else, so I believe its worth sharing.